# Positioning of Constant C in Antiderivative

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

Standard notation would just include a $C$ as constant in the end, as below:

$y = f(x) + C$

however I see quite a few tutorials/text books that just use

$y = Cf(x)$, especially when $ln()$ is encountered.

How can we transform the standard notation to the notation where $C$ is a coefficient of the $f(x)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are generally mistaken about alternate forms. One does indeed usually have an additive constant. However, you can sometimes manipulate the result into something different.

For example, when you solve $y' = y$, you get a separable differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} = y$$ which separates into $$\frac{dy}{y} = dx.$$ Now, integrating both sides you get
$$
\ln y + C_1 = x + C_2,
$$
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants. Then, so is $K = C_2-C_1$ and we can write
$$
\ln y = x + K
$$
and exponentiate both sides to get
$$
y = e^{x+K} = e^K e^x = Ce^x,
$$
where $$C = e^K = e^{C_2-C_1}.$$

As you can see, $C$ is just a algebraic modification of the original additive constants.

Comment: There are also differential equations where the constant of integration ends up entirely elsewhere in the equation.  For example, if we try to solve $dy/dx = -y^2$, integrating yields $1/y = x + C$, or $y = 1/(x + C)$.  The constant $C$ that appears in the solution for $y(x)$ is neither additive nor multiplicative.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I agree, but it is still a product of an algebraic transformation of the same additive constant of integration...

Comment: thanks @gt6989b it is indeed what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $y=f(x)+C$ is a somewhat lousy way of denoting the set of functions $x\mapsto f(x)+C$, where $f$ is a given function and $C$ is an arbitrary real constant. Similarly, writing $y=C f(x)$ is  a somewhat lousy way of denoting the set of functions $x\mapsto C\,f(x)$, where $f$ is a given function and $C$ is an arbitrary real constant. Depending on the context solution sets of certain problems, e.g., finding the set of all primitives of a function $g$, are of one of these kinds.

Comment: thanks for pointing to me the appropriate form of notation here, it does better denote 'the set of functions'. but I don't quite get how this answer the actual question here, could you shed more light here?

Answer (score 0):

If we have $\ln y=f(x)+C_0$, then we exponentiate to find an expression for $y$ itself:

$$y=e^{f(x)+C_0}=e^{C_0}e^{f(x)}=CF(x),$$

where we are taking $C=e^{C_0}$ and $F(x)=e^{f(x)}$.

In short, exponentiation turns addition into multiplication, so an added constant becomes a multiplied coefficient.

Comment: yes i wasn't so clear on how to turn addition into multiplication.